# How to return a value from a table or dataframe given 2 inputs? Python

Tags: python, dataframe

Let's say this is my dataframe:
[image]

and the user inputs B and 2

Then the function would return clemintine

Is there a way to do this without using a bunch of if elif statements. The actual dataframe I'm working with is much  larger and it would take a long time to do with if elif statements.

Essentially I want the user to enter a row index value and a column index value and the function returns the corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

If you define you row starting value as 0 then you can achieve this by the following code

```
import pandas as pd

# define sample data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'A': ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Strawberry'],
  'B': ['Banana', 'Clementine', 'Blackberry'],
  'C': ['Strawberry', 'Blackberry', 'Peach']})

# get user input
selected_row = int(input('Please enter the row that you want to specify: '))
selected_column = input('Please enter the column that you want to specify: ')

# return value
cell_value = df[selected_column].iloc[selected_row]

print(cell_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.loc[2,'B']` is probably the simplest way to get 'Clementine'. It avoids "chain indexing", and I heard that's good.