# reading specific row and column to get the amount in csv with python

Tags: python

I am trying to read for a CSV file to print to another CSV. What I need is to get the specific line in a row.

csv source is:

```
hotdog, 3.99
burger, 4.99
ice cream, 2.50
soda, 1.50
```

What I need is to get the amount of each row only for specific row and the amount. Say I need to get the amount of hotdog to get the total value from the Entry box.

My code is below:

```py
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import csv

item = []
def checkout(): # Checkout button function
    """write the receipt"""
    with open("order.csv", "r") as file:
        reader = file.read() # to get the total prices on checkout
        #for line in file_contents:
         #   milk = line[1]

        global root, hotdogbox, burgerbox, icecreambox, sodabox
        with open("writereceipt.csv", "w") as file:
            receipt = csv.writer(file, lineterminator = "\n")

            for item in reader:
                hotdog = item
                for row in hotdog:
                    item.append(row)
                    total_hotdog = int(hotdogbox.get())

                    if total_hotdog >= 1:
                        hotdog_cost = total_hotdog * hotdog
                        hotdog_total = ["Milk: ", total_hotdog, hotdog_cost]           
                        space = ["----------","--", "------------"]
                        total = hotdog_cost 
                        total_output = ["Total: ", "", total]
                        receipt.writerow(hotdog_total)
                        receipt.writerow(total_output)
```

My code is not working...... It will print MM as total...

Comment: I answered this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61295990/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-table-or-dataframe-given-2-inputs-python/61296162#61296162

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for answering. What I need is to get the price for each row only to multiply it with the result from entry box.1st row is the hotdog, 2nd is burger, then ice cream then the soda